# What happens when user ignores one version of application and installs later version in Android or iOS?

Tags: android, ios

Suppose I have two application version 1.1 and 1.2 on the market(1.1 is the first released version).
What happens when a user ignores version 1.1 and install 1.2 on the device? What if the content of version 1.1 is dependent on 1.2?

Comment: They should be standalone applications. I didn't think it was possible to have an app rely on a older version. That's just a bad design.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Lets say I have added some new features in version 1.1 and these features are used in 1.2. In such case, do I let the user to install version 1.1 strictly?

Comment: Since you added those features in 1.1 that means you have the feature in 1.2 already....

Comment: @SujinShrestha Why not just put the new features in 1.2 and have them upgrade? What benefit is there to using an older version?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by content ?

In short if you have any database, or data structure managed by you, you need to provide a way in your code to handle the upgrade scenarios (like altering the tables, or data structures). You can use versioning to do it and write code to upgrade from each version to the current one. Downgrading usually is not permitted without uninstalling the application, so you are safe there.

Comment: by content i mean like adding a complete new feature

Comment: Why would you add a complete new feature to the 1.1 version ? If you do so it would become 1.3 because can't be 1.2 (it has to have a bigger version code then the 1.2 to be able to upload to google play store)